# can't alter the default value from null to 0000-00-00 for date column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which previous developer make a `date` type column with default value `null`. Now I want to change the default value to `0000-00-00`. but I am getting below error.

> ## 1067 - Invalid default value

All records are in format of `0000-00-00`.

is there any way to do this.

[image]

Client updated the `mysql` version So facing the below issue.

Able to alter table with using

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.5
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost:3306
-- Generation Time: Mar 17, 2016 at 03:59 PM
-- Server version: 5.7.11
-- PHP Version: 5.6.14

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

**Without header `update`, `insert` and `alter` query is not working**

Comment: Use NULL for unknown/not specified.

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you tried `0000-00-00 00:00:00`? and if there's no tick next to "null", tick it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's a date field, not a time field. Regardless, I don't think having separate fields for date and time is a good idea. Why not have one `fm_depart_datetime` column?

Comment: @HugoZink I just tested this on my own machine and it worked. I even tried with both DATE and DATETIME types. So, unsure why it's not working for him.

Comment: Don't know whats going on. Working on local not on live.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using quotes around the date? `'0000-00-00'`

This should be the correct zero value for a DATE type ([mySQL reference manual 11.3 Date and Time Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html))

If it still doesn't work, perhaps you can check the value of [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date).